# Control MapFragment through overlaying view

Tags: android, scrollview, android-view, supportmapfragment

I have a following layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:id="@+id/map" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root_container"
        android:paddingTop="240dp" />
    </ScrollView>


</FrameLayout>
```

In the map framelayout I have a MapFragment which is effectivelly overlaid by the scrollview..I want to have the scrollview content to scroll over it, so I have it placed on top of the fragment. There is also padding to make the map initally visible..
The problem is I can't interact with the map through the overlaying view. I've tried to subclass the scrollview and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method, but it still does not work..Any thoughts how to solve that? Thanks